# Facebook Comment box not expanding

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add the Facebook Comment Box Widget to a website, but the predetermined height set by facebook cuts the box off to where you can only see one comment at a time.

I've looked all over the internet, and it seems that this was an issue a couple years ago, and it effected just about every site that had one of these widgets, but I've yet to come across a current site that is having this issue, which leads me to believe that the old problem was fixed at some point.

I've tried overriding the Facebook CSS with:

```
 .fb_ltr{max-height:px !important;}
```

But all this ends up doing is taking it to whatever height you set, and then cuts it off like before. Has anyone else had this problem either recently or in the past? is there a way to fix it? clearly some websites out there are making it work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" ;type="text/css"; href="test.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script>(function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>



     <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-   posts="10"></div>            

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you can not inject css in fb p;ugins

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Just a thought, are you sure it's the comment plugin? do you have it inside div tags on your website that is cutting off the bottom bart of the plugin?

Comment: yes it is the comments plugin, and I get the same result when it's in or out of a div.

Comment: Can we see the code you are using for the plugin?

Comment: I have edited the original post with the updated code

Comment: Your code works OK for me, tested it on Firefox and Chrome, I can see all comments.

Comment: Just a guess, What if you remove "<link rel="stylesheet" ;type="text/css"; href="test.css"/>" any difference?

Comment: this is weird, when I was testing it locally on my system it wasnt working properly, but then when I uploaded it to a free server it formatted it correctly.

Comment: Ah OK, we know it's not the code then :-)

Comment: Browser cache? not sure if it's that but just posted anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this when using facebook's plugin. You need to pull the posts through manually using some JSON, there are lots of tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS file of your plugin, you have to delete all the codes like:

```
.facebook-comment { width: 95px !important; }
```

Theses codes are settled by the plugin but doesn't match whit all themes and websites.

Once you've done this, you can create a new `<div class=fb-comment>` or something like that in order to customize your facebook comment box as you want (to replace it, to set-up the width, etc.)